# Select only first item from two-line paper-dropdown-menu

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm using polymer 2.0-preview.
I have `<paper-dropdown-menu>` like this:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Your devices..." style="margin: 0;">
    <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" selected="1">
        <paper-icon-item>
            <iron-icon icon="hardware:phone-android" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
            <paper-item-body two-line>
                <div>PLAY LGE LG-H440n</div>
                <div secondary>Last sync: Jan 9, 2014</div>
            </paper-item-body>
        </paper-icon-item>
        <paper-icon-item value="PLAY ASUS Nexus7 2012 WIFI">
            <iron-icon icon="hardware:tablet-android" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
            <paper-item-body two-line>
                <div>PLAY ASUS Nexus7 2012 WIFI</div>
                <div secondary>last sync: Jan 9, 2014</div>
            </paper-item-body>
        </paper-icon-item>
    </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

When I select for example first item, what I get is

> PLAY LGE LG-H440nLast sync: Jan 9, 2014

what I want is

> PLAY LGE LG-H440n

I need to display only first line. I tried to set `value` to `<paper-icon-item>` but it doesn't work. How can I do it without creating my own component? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've got it. As per docummentation in `paper-dropdown-menu.html` file:

```
<paper-input
    type="text"
    invalid="[[invalid]]"
    readonly
    disabled="[[disabled]]"
    value="[[selectedItemLabel]]"
    placeholder="[[placeholder]]"
    error-message="[[errorMessage]]"
    always-float-label="[[alwaysFloatLabel]]"
    no-label-float="[[noLabelFloat]]"
    label="[[label]]">

...

/**
 * The derived "label" of the currently selected item. This value
 * is the `label` property on the selected item if set, or else the
 * trimmed text content of the selected item.
 */
 selectedItemLabel: {
     type: String,
     notify: true,
     readOnly: true
 }
```

I need to set `label` on my `<paper-icon-item>` element.